# Remove Side Effect from an angular function

Tags: javascript, angular, unit-testing, typescript, side-effects

I am making a method that receive two parameters, `options` and `data`, but in the return values only return `options`, I want to implement unit testing on this project and I want to avoid **side effects** on this method to do it testeable, I am figure out witch is the best approach to do this, return an array with two values for each one or split this method in two small methods that return different values.

This is my method simplified for demostration:

```
private setEst(data, options): object {

    const numCols: number = data.getColNumber();    
    const indxRows: Array<Number> = data.getIndexRows();
    const otherArray: : object[] = [];

    // Creating options output that will be returned
    for (let col = 1; col < numCols; col++) {
        // Do something with options to modify the value of this param
        ...

        // Read data to create an array that will be used by the next process
        otherArray.push({
          id: data(col).getId();
        });
      }
    }

    // Output data as a side effect
    indxRows.forEach(indx => {
      for (let col = 1; col < numCols; col++) {

        // Do something with data object and otherArray const, 
        // data is modified and returned as side effect...
        ...


      }
    });

    return options;
}
```